# how to keep journal_mode for every transaction

Tags: sqlite, pragma

I am using `"PRAGMA journal_mode= OFF"` in my code but it seems that my database is not keeping this setting. When i reconnect to my database it shows `"PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE"`. Why is this happening? Is there any chance I can make it constant for all the connections in my database?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) says:

> This pragma ... sets the journal mode for databases associated with the current database connection.

There is no mechanism to save it in the database file.
You have to set it for every connection.

Comment: This no longer appears to be correct. "The WAL journaling mode is persistent; after being set it stays in effect across multiple database connections and after closing and reopening the database"

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE This does not apply to the OFF/DELETE modes, which this question is about.